# Solenoid flyback, relayboard switch

Tags: power, motor

I want to open a solenoid valve with an arduino, and have set up the following circuit

[image]

The plan is to add solenoids to every relay on the board. I am wondering if this circuit is any useful, or if there are major flaws present. I am worried about frying my components, especially the 12V 2A hooked up with a solenoid of 1A, however i want the 2A, since i want to be able to power multiple solenoids at the same time.

I tried switching the board directly from the arduino, and with its 5V to the VCC, but it was not enough to make the relays switch, maybe a transistor is in line, if so, which one?

Comment: What relay board are you using? Specs?

Comment: 12V, has diodes built in, capacity is AC250V 10A, DC30V 10A. Found no other specs.

Comment: @LookAlterno and Rasmus  If the relays are 12V, then they should get 12V. The 2A is no problem. What is that 9V doing? Should that be 5V to the logic part of the relay board? Is that for the optocouplers? Is your Arduino board only powered with a usb cable? Can you give a link to your relay board?